# Return records not having relation to ANY given ID of related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have `alerts` table. `alerts` have many `regulations` through `alert_regulations` join table.

I need to fetch `alerts` which do not have any of given `regulation` ids.

My attempt was:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "alerts".* FROM "alerts"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "alert_regulations" ON "alert_regulations"."alert_id" = "alerts"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "regulations" ON "regulations"."id" = "alert_regulations"."regulation_id"
WHERE "regulations"."id" NOT IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

or, avoiding one join:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "alerts".* FROM "alerts"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "alert_regulations" ON "alert_regulations"."alert_id" = "alerts"."id"
WHERE "alert_regulations"."regulation_id" NOT IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

However, if alert has any other regulation than $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, it still gets returned.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM alerts a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM alert_regulations ar
                  WHERE ar.alert_id = a.id AND
                        ar.regulation_id IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
                 );
```

I would strongly advise you to NOT use double quotes around column and table names.  They just make queries harder to write and read -- and open the potential to identifiers that differ only in the upper-case versus lower-case letters.  That can lead to errors.

Also, Postgres supports arrays, so you could pass in a list of values as an array.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works like a charm :) I'm also super happy about avoiding `joins` and `distinct`. You have a small typo in your answer - it should be `WHERE ar.alert_id = a.id`. About the double quotes - I'm using Rails' ActiveRecord ORM, unfortunately that's how it does it under the hood.